# How to pass the print function as argument to a forEach?

Tags: swift, types, closures, contravariance, liskov-substitution-principle

The `print` function can print integers and can be called like `print(5)`. I want to do the same on an `[Int]` array.

However attempting to do the same on a `forEach` fails.

```
[1,2,3].forEach(print)
```

gives

```
expression failed to parse:
error: repl.swift:20:17: error: cannot convert value of type
 '(Any..., String, String) -> ()' to expected argument type 
'(Int) throws -> Void'

[1,2,3].forEach(print)
                ^
```

How can I get Swift to perform this conversion from `(Any, ... String, String) -> ()` to `(Int) throws -> Void` without resorting to the workarounds listed below?

Aren't function types *contravariant* in the parameter position, meaning that since `Any` is a supertype of `Int`, `(Any, ... String, String) -> ()` is a subtype of `(Int) throws -> Void` (since `()` is the same as `Void`) and therefore by the Liskov substitution principle, `print` should be a perfectly acceptable argument to `forEach` in this case?

Is it an issue with the number of (variadic AND optional!) parameters in `(Any, ... String, String)`?

#### Workarounds

These work but they seem unnecessary to me.
Creating an inline closure using shorthand argument name `[1,2,3].forEach { print($0) }` or defining a function `func printInt(_ n: Int) { print(n) }; [1,2,3].forEach(printInt)` both work.

This suggests that the issue is at least partly with the number of arguments. However I am not clearly understanding what is happening here and would appreciate any help.

Comment: "Is it an issue with the number of (variadic AND optional!) parameters in (Any, ... String, String)?" **Yes**

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper - is there anything more concise I can do to fix the issue, apart from the "wrapping" that I do in the "Workarounds" section of my question?

Comment: You can declare your own "function transformer" that turns a `(Any..., String, String) -> Void` into a `(Any) -> Void`, but I'd say that is also "wrapping". You just have to wrap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it an issue with the number of (variadic AND optional!) parameters in `(Any, ... String, String)`?

Yes. There is no syntax for function type parameters that say "this is an optional parameter". When you treat `print` as a first class object, its optional parameters automatically becomes required.

```
let p = print
// p's type is (Any..., String, String) -> Void

func notOptionalPrint(_ items: Any..., separator: String, terminator: String) { ... }
let q = notOptionalPrint
// q's type is also (Any..., String, String) -> Void
```

Furthermore, the type of the first parameter is `Any...`. *This is not the same as `Any`.* It is not a supertype of `Int` or `Any`, so LSP does not apply here, even if the optional parameters problem is magically solved.

Therefore, you have to wrap it in some way if you want to pass it directly to `forEach`. Rather than wrapping it just for `Int`, you can consider wrapping it for `Any`:

```
func print(_ x: Any) {
    // need "Swift." here, otherwise infinite recursion
    Swift.print(x)
}
```

Then, because of LSP, you can pass this directly to `forEach` for collections of any element type.

Personally though, I wouldn't bother, and just use `forEach { print($0) }`.

Answer (score 1):

This is another workaround if you only care about using `print`:

```
extension Sequence {
    func printEach() {
        for element in self {
            print(element)
        }
    }
}

[1,2,3].printEach()
```

Or a variation of your `printInt` workaround that works with any type:

```
func printElement(_ element: Any) {
    print(element)
}

[1,2,3].forEach(printElement)
```

Neither are very appealing to me and just using the `print($0)` closure is likely to be clearer to people reading the code.